# New HTMLService Parameters Passing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass parameters using the Google Apps Script.  Specifically, this is a dialog inside a SpreadsheetApp service.  Here is a simple code of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
function confirmation() {
    var a = 6;
    var b = 7;
    var HTMLoutput = 'Would you like to add these numbers?';
    HTMLoutput += '<input type="button" value="Yes" ';
    HTMLoutput += 'onclick="google.script.run.confirmed(a, b)" />';
    HTMLoutput += '<input type="button" value="No" ';
    HTMLoutput += 'onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
        HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLoutput), '');
}

function confirmed(a, b) {
    Logger.log(a+b);
}
```

For some reason, the parameters are not passing.  I have a feeling it has to do with how the variables are inside a String.  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using lots of text formulas for all your HTML, you can sometimes use `append`:

```
var HTMLoutput = '';
HTMLoutput.append("<div>This is appended HTML</div>");
```

The text formulas are hard to understand and debug.  You will still need to use them, but maybe this will make it easier.

The `onclick` event needs to reference the code in the HTML.  Right now, it's pointing at the google script.  Maybe try this:

```
onclick="confirmed(a, b)"
```

### The entire code would be

```
function confirmation() {
  var a = 6;
  var b = 7;
  var HTMLoutput = '';

  HTMLoutput += '<script>function confirmed(' + a + "," + b + ') {' +
  'Logger.log(a);' +
  'Logger.log(b);' +
  'google.script.run.confirmed(a, b);' +
  'google.script.host.close();}</script>'


  HTMLoutput += '<input type="button" value="Yes" ';
  HTMLoutput += 'onclick="confirmed(a, b)" />';
  HTMLoutput += '<input type="button" value="No" ';
  HTMLoutput += 'onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLoutput), '');
}
```

### gs code

```
function confirmed(a, b) {
  //code here
};
```

Note that you have two functions named `confirmed`, one in the HTML, and one in the `.gs` server code.

Comment: This code is just a simple example of what I am trying to achieve.  My code isn't actually looking to just log the variables.  There is a lot of data manipulation that goes into `function confirmed(a, b)` that is just not visible in the example above.

Comment: So, you gave an example that is not representative of your actual situation?

Comment: Hello. It is representative--I stated that my purpose is that I'm trying to pass the parameters into `function confirmed(a, b)`, which it is not doing.  I'm not sure why it's not passing the parameters.  I apologize if that was confusing in the question.

Comment: Every time I learn something new, and have trouble, it's very frustrating because I don't even know what I should be asking for a question.  I wish I had an easy answer for you.  Basically, if you want values `a` and `b` to be able to be passed **out** of the HTML, they need to **in** the HTML.  Your values aren't in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The HTMLoutput is HTML string that will display from the `showModalDialog()` at the bottom of the first function.  Basically, my code is giving two buttons with the options of Yes or No.  If they click yes, I need it to run that second function and pass the parameters into the second function.  That is the part where I am stuck.  >.<

Comment: Okay, now I think I understand what the problem is.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  Okay, so I guess it would've helped for me to mention that both functions live in a `.gs` server code.  It's in the script file of Spreadsheet document.  The function `confirmation()` is called when someone clicks on that item from the menu in the Spreadsheet Ui.  Do I have to have a separate HTML file in order to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I just realized that there is a mistake in my answer.  I should have put the function into an HTML `<script>` tag.  Please see updated answer.  Are you familiar with `console.log()` statements?  That can tell you what the HTML code is doing.  Open the browsers console to see the console.log print info.

Comment: Hello.  I apologize for the many responses.  You have no idea how helpful you are being.  Where does the `<script>` go?

Comment: I realized that my example had another error.  I fixed it.  The variables `a` and `b` are not text.  The variables can't be inside quotes.  You must concatenate the values to the text with a plus sign.